# Check if there are speakable characters in a string - swift text to speech

Tags: swift, string, character, text-to-speech

I am making an app where the user can enter something and it will be spoken.

I know how to check if there is any content in the string:

```
speech != ""
```

But, this does not account for spaces.

Is there a way to check if a string has any characters where pressing the space bar will not count as a character?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeWhitespacesFromString(_ string: String) -> String {
    return string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
}

let string = "  Hello world  "
let result = removeWhitespacesFromString(string)
print(result)  // "Hello world"
if !result.isEmpty {
    // text to speech
}
```